# How to execute a class file (include Main()) in my package folder on Jboss system as standalone

Tags: java, jboss, program-entry-point

I hava a java project deployed in Jboss. When jboss started completely, I have to execute a class file that has a `main()` method automatically when jboss starts. that means TESTManager should be as like a standalone daemon. I have no idea how to execute it automatically in my project...

The class is provided below:

```
public class TESTMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TESTManager testManager = new TESTManager();
            testManager.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```